# Fail to validate XML with Schematron.NET

Tags: c#, xml, schematron

I am using Schematron.NET in a C# project to validate the XML (format below):

```
<bpr:item xmlns:bpr="http://etcetc.com">
<bpr:name>Title</bpr:name>
<bpr:contents>
<process>Process1</process>
</bpr:contents>
</bpr:item>
```

The sch file contains the following code:

```
<ns prefix="bpr" uri="http://etcetc.com"/>
<pattern name="Title" xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
<rule context="item/contents">
<assert test="process='Process2'">Process not found.</assert>
</rule>
</pattern>
```

And this is the C# using NMatrix.Schematron.dll:

```
Validator val = new Validator();
XPathDocument docnav = new XPathDocument(xmlPath);
XPathNavigator nav = docnav.CreateNavigator();
nav.MoveToRoot();
val.AddSchema(schemaFilePath);
val.ValidateSchematron(nav);
```

Why is it not retrieving any results?

Comment: welcome - please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry Daniel, let me include the C# for you to replicate.

Comment: The schema is not well formed and is being ignored.  A well formed XML file has only one root tag.  Your schema has both ns and pattern at root.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. Do you happen to know how could I group them in one root tag?

Comment: string xml = "<root>" + your_xml + "</root>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to the C# code, but here are some things in the Schematron code:

1. As mentioned in the comments, the Schematron code should have a single document element. In Schematron, it is the `<schema>` element.
2. When you refer to elements in the "`http://etcetc.com`" namespace, you need to use the "`bpr:`" namespace prefix that you declared in the Schematron schema.
3. The Schematron `<pattern>` element cannot have a `@name` attribute. It can have an `@id` attribute or a `<title>` child element (both are optional).

Here's a working example of the Schematron code that generates a failed assert on the sample XML document you provided:

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
  <ns prefix="bpr" uri="http://etcetc.com"/>
  <pattern>
    <rule context="bpr:item/bpr:contents">
      <assert test="process='Process2'">Process not found.</assert>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
</schema>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. However I believe NMatrix.Schematron.NET does not support ISO Schematron, as it only works if I switch http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron for http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron.

Comment: Ok. In the ASCC version of Schematron, `<pattern>` can have a `@name` attribute. But as you noted, you have to declare your schema as being in the  `http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron` namespace rather than the `http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron` namespace used by the ISO version of Schematron.